# mutual information and prediction accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, information-theory

what's the relation between mutual information and predict accuracy for classification or MSE for regression? Is it possible to have high accuracy/low MSE with low mutual information in data mining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutual information is defined for pairs of probability distributions. Much of what can be said regarding its relationship to other quantities depends heavily on how you compute and represent these probability distributions (e.g. discrete versus continuous probability distributions).

Given a set of probability distributions, the relationship between classification accuracy and mutual information has been [studied in the literature](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15829089). In short, one quantity puts bounds on the other, at least for discrete probability distributions.

I don't know of any formal studies looking at the relationship between the MSE and mutual information.

All of that being said, if I had a concrete data set and got low mutual information scores for two variables but also a very low MSE in a regression model, I would take a hard look at how the mutual information was computed. 99 out of 100 times this occurs because the original formulation of Shannon entropy (and by extension mutual information) is used on continuous / floating point data, even though this method only applies to discrete data.